# alter data type of existing column from bigint to varchar in Apache derby

Tags: sql, derby

I am using Apache derby database v 10.9.1.0. There is one existing table **Country**-having column **LawID of type bigint**. It contains records having integer data only. Due to some business reason, I need to alter its data type from '**bigint**' to '**varchar**' . I tried following two ways to alter existing table. But both ways did not work.

*a. first way*

```
    ALTER TABLE Country ADD COLUMN LawID_NEW VARCHAR(50);
    UPDATE Country SET LawID_NEW  = LawID;
    ALTER TABLE Country DROP COLUMN LawID;
    RENAME COLUMN Country.LawID_NEW TO LawID;
```

It shows message like :Columns of type 'VARCHAR' cannot hold values of type 'BIGINT'.

*b. second way*

```
ALTER TABLE Country ALTER LawID SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```

It shows error message like : Invalid type specified for column 'LawID'. The type of a column may not be changed.

Any help related to correct alter query  is highly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first method would work with this change:

```
UPDATE Country SET LawID_NEW = TRIM(CHAR(LawID));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname VARCHAR(20);
```

This works in mysql. Give it a try.

Or

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE columnname columnname VARCHAR(20);
```